# How to filter JSON and get value in iOS Swift?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to filter JSON and get key & value to parse it. Here all JSON values are dynamic. Right now I need to find "type = object" if the type found is true then I need to check value ={"contentType" & "URL"}.

here is my JSON:

```
{
    "date": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "03/04/1982",
        "valueInfo": {}
    },
    "Scanner": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": {
            "contentType": "image/jpeg ",
            "url": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/neon-advertisement-on-library-glass-wall-9832438/",
            "fileName": "sample.jpeg"
        },
        "valueInfo": {
            "objectTypeName": "com.google.gson.JsonObject",
            "serializationDataFormat": "application/json"
        }
    },
    "startedBy": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "super",
        "valueInfo": {}
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "kucoin",
        "valueInfo": {}
    },
    "ScannerDetails": {
        "type": "Json",
        "value": {
            "accountNumber": "ANRPM2537J",
            "dob": "03/04/1982",
            "fathersName": "VASUDEV MAHTO",
            "name": "PRAMOD KUMAR MAHTO"
        },
        "valueInfo": {}
    }
}
```

decode code:

```
          AF.request(v , method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:AFDataResponse<Any>) in
        
        
        print("process instance id api document view list::::",response.result)
        
        
        
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            
            let matchingUsers = response.value.flatMap { $0 }.flatMap { $0. == "object" }
            
            print("new object doc:::", matchingUsers)
            
            guard let data = response.value  else {
                return
            }
           
            
            print("new object doc:::", matchingUsers)
            
            if let newJSON = response.value {
                
                let json = newJSON as? [String: [String:Any]]
                                    print("new object doc:::", json as Any)
        
  //                    let dictAsString = self.asString(jsonDictionary: json)
                
                let vc = self.stringify(json: json ?? [])
                
                print("dictAsString ::: dictAsString::::==",vc)
                
                let data = vc.data(using: .utf8)!
                   do{
                       let output = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: [String:String]]
                       print ("demo:::==\(String(describing: output))")
                   }
                   catch {
                       print (error)
                   }
                
            
                do {
                    if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [String: [String:String]]
                    {
                        print("json array::::",jsonArray) // use the json here
                    } else {
                        print("bad json")
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
                
                
            }
            
            self.view.removeLoading()
            
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error:", error)
            self.view.removeLoading()
        }
        
    }
```

How to get specific values from JSON? Any help is much appreciated pls...

Comment: "here is my son"  Your 'son' is not in the JSON format.

Comment: @ElTomato updated JSON. Help me on this.

Comment: @PvUIDev you need to re-decode the content of `value` because it's still in a string format. If you still have trouble I can show you the code you need to do this. but I think you should show an attempt first

Comment: @Jacob can you show a sample of this?

Comment: Where is you decoding code?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson updated the code. please check it.

Comment: go to site json4swift a json parser paster your json there and click on generate code then add  all files to your project change then Name of struct JSon4Swift_Base to (Any Good Name Related to API) like as MyJSONData
after that i ll tell you the next single  line of code in json response to handle data

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed all values are dynamic. I need to filter type == object and contentType & url

Comment: Don't use JSONSerialization in Swift, use `JsonDecoder`. There are hundreds of tutorial about this exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code from my playground with your json sample:

```swift
import Foundation

let json = """
{
    "date": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "03/04/1982",
        "valueInfo": {}
    },
    "Scanner": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": {
            "contentType": "image/jpeg ",
            "url": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/neon-advertisement-on-library-glass-wall-9832438/",
            "fileName": "sample.jpeg"
        },
        "valueInfo": {
            "objectTypeName": "com.google.gson.JsonObject",
            "serializationDataFormat": "application/json"
        }
    },
    "startedBy": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "super",
        "valueInfo": {}
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "kucoin",
        "valueInfo": {}
    },
    "ScannerDetails": {
        "type": "Json",
        "value": {
            "accountNumber": "ANRPM2537J",
            "dob": "03/04/1982",
            "fathersName": "VASUDEV MAHTO",
            "name": "PRAMOD KUMAR MAHTO"
        },
        "valueInfo": {}
    }
}
"""

let data = json.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

struct ObjectScanner: Decodable {
    let contentType: String
    let url: String
    let fileName: String
}

enum ObjectScannerType {
    case object(ObjectScanner)
}

struct Scanner: Decodable {
    enum ScannerType: String, Decodable {
        case object = "Object"
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type, value
    }

    let scanner: ObjectScannerType

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let type = try container.decode(ScannerType.self, forKey: .type)

        switch type {
        case .object:
            let value = try container.decode(ObjectScanner.self, forKey: .value)
            scanner = .object(value)
        }
    }
}

struct DateResponse: Decodable {
    let type: String
    let value: String
    // let valueInfo // Not enough information in sample for me to decode this object
}

struct Response: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date
        case scanner = "Scanner"
    }

    let date: DateResponse
    let scanner: Scanner
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let response = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print("Error decoding: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Note: this example is very unforgiving. Any missing value or type that is not supported will lead to a `DecodingError`. It's up to you to determine all possible types and what is optional and what is not.

I also didn't decode everything nor do I handle the `date` object to it's fullest

This is as json goes a very complex example. Everything in it is polymorphic: the `date`, the `Scanner`, the `ScannerDetails`, etc. You need to be very careful how you decode this and make sure you handle all possibilities. I would suggest that if you're starting out, you should explore simpler examples.

I also chose to use enums. Not something everyone would chose but its my preference for decoding polymorphic types such as these.

You can read my article about dealing with polymorphic types as well as unknown types here: https://medium.com/@jacob.sikorski/awesome-uses-of-swift-enums-2ff011a3b5a5